# How do I convert created date 2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z (ISO 1861) string to Date Time in Powery Query?

Tags: datetime, powerbi, powerquery

I get a created date in data from a SharePoint Online list to Power BI, which looks like this "2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z"[in ISO 1861]. I want to convert it in order to obtain a Date or String object and get something like "01-04-2018" that its "dd-MM-YYYY". How can I do it in power Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might be using Implementation 2.0 while connecting to SharePoint list.  Try to connect via 1.0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The conversion should be automatic if you set the type to datetime

[image]

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes("PriorStepNameHere",{{"Column1", type datetime}})
```

Comment: its troughing an error in created date.

Comment: you didn't post your sample input, or code, so there is no way for me to assist you. Works fine  for me, with data shown, column names shown, with my local date/time set to format for US

Answer (score 0):

you don't need do use power query, you can just use the column tools in data exibition, there's a format option where you can choose which data format you want.